# Linearize non-linear constraint (product of two continuous variables)

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, linearization

I have a problem with linearizing a constraint because of the product of two continuous variables.

Suppose that the non-linear constraint is A = b + x1 x2      : A,x1,x2 are non-negative continuous variables.

How can I linearize this constraint?

I tried to reformulate it by creating two new continuous variables (y1 and y2)
where y1 = 1/2 (x1 + x2)  and y2= 1/2 (x1 - x2).
In this case, the constraint also becomes non-linear.

What should I do?

Comment: It's in R , Python, matlab, other ?

Comment: @phili_b, do you know any function in Pyomo, Julia, anywhere which does this McCormick transformation of the expression?

Comment: The model is applied in AMPL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no exact way to linearize `w=x*y` if x and y are continuous.

- The reformulation `z1 = 1/2 (x + y)` and `z2 = 1/2 (x - y)` gives `w = z1^2 - z2^2`. This is indeed still non-linear, but this is easier to handle when using a piecewise linear approximation.
- You can use McCormick envelopes (https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/McCormick_envelopes). But this gives just an approximation. To get more precision, split the range in segments.
- Sometimes (in special cases) a logarithmic transform can help.
- Some solvers can handle this quadratic expression directly.